# Excel formula to compare in attached sheet

Tags: excel-formula

sheet one :Data file contains all the data 
Sheet two : i want to check the clash between two courses mentioned as course 1 and course 2 and display the roll number and name of students in sheet 2

http://www.qfpost.com/file/d?g=DnXUNvEMg

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you should do the following:

In `sheet1`: Copy the formula `=A2` in `K2` & `=B2` in `L2`, drag them down to the end of table.

In `Sheet2`: Copy the formula `=VLOOKUP(IF(A2=B2,A2,"error"),Sheet1!$D$2:$L$10101,8,)` in `C2` & `=VLOOKUP(IF(A2=B2,A2,"error"),Sheet1!$D$2:$L$10101,9,)` in `D2` and drag them down to the end of table.

Using `Vlookup()` function required to match the first column in the given range as reference.

`Logic I Used:` (in Sheet2 cell C2) If A2 equals to B2 then fetch the Roll Number for A2 from Sheet1 Range $D$2:$L$10101.
(in Sheet2 cell D2) If A2 equals to B2 then fetch the St.Name for A2 from Sheet1 Range $D$2:$L$10101.